# Which sentence is the more idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Shall I wait until you **are coming** back from your vacation?

Shall I wait until you **come** back from your vacation ?

I think the first one is the more idiomatic because it is not a habit and it is a long trip .

Comment: Both need a question mark! The first one means that you suggest waiting until they are about to travel, or are in the process of travelling, home from the vacation. If you mean 'until you are at home again', use the second.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure what it is you're waiting to do, but let's imagine it's phone them.

I don't like the first at all. It just sounds wrong, in quite a particular way* that says "English is not my first language", which of course is why we're here to help;)
It makes it sound like you're going to call them whilst they're on the plane.
The second at least hints that you'll wait for them to get home.

I'd prefer

> Shall I wait until you're back from your vacation?

or

> Shall I wait until you're [back] home?

*Maybe a proper grammarian can explain precisely *why* this is wrong, but it is wrong & it's a common mistake in ESL speakers. Back in the days we were less considerate towards other cultures, it was used as a linguistic cue to indicate the speaker was Indian. I'm not sure why, but it was a distinct 'racial stereotype' joke. Look up old episodes of "It Ain't Half Hot, Mum" for a whole slew of those, which wouldn't get past the censors these days.

Comment: OP's first version isn't "wrong". Per @Kate's comment, it just doesn't mean what OP thinks. It means speaker is suggesting he might wait until addressee is *en route* (or at least, *about to travel*), where almost certainly OP means until the addressee *has actually returned* (i.e. - ***after*** traveling).

Comment: Pretty sure that's exactly what I said.

Comment: What I'm reading above is *I don't like the first at all. It just sounds wrong*. Which is incorrect.

Comment: It does sound wrong, because that's very unlikely to be what they meant. It's Michael Bates Indian-English.

Comment: No. Its perfectly valid syntax. It just ***doesn't mean what OP thinks.***

Comment: Correct. Just what I already said. I don't know what it is that you're reading into my answer that means we seem to be agreeing so loudly.

Comment: I dn't understand your comments at all. Obviously *Shall I wait until you are coming back from your vacation?* is perfectly valid ***if*** what the speaker is suggesting is that he should wait until the addressee is *in the process of returning*. I'm sure that's not the meaning the OP intends - but it ***is*** syntactically valid, so the second paragraph of your answer text is obviously incorrect.

Comment: No, it's not. I never once said it was 'syntactically incorrect' you just **read** it that way. "It's wrong" == "no-one would ever say what we think you mean by using that phrase, because it uses a weird continuous present that is a racially stereotypical joke."